# Updating Ubuntu on Dell Latitude E7240 (factory install)

Tags: 12.04, dell, laptop, displayport, hardware-certification

I have a Dell Latitude E7240 as my work machine. It came with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed. I would like to upgrade to a later distro but it is important that I don't end up witha  buggy machine a s a result.

Has anyone with a factory version of 12.04 dist-upgraded who can comment on it? Has it caused you any issues? Did you go to 14.04 or another distro? Do you use a docking station and does this work?

Are the Dell utilities overwritten or do they remain intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work nicely, it have done so on my Latitude E6510.
But just in case download the driver package from dell:

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=0WKFN

Here on Ubuntu you can get a 12.04 image:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201304-13407/

Those downloads is just in case Murphy raises his ugly head during upgrade.
Your Dell utilities will only be replaced if there are newer updated drivers!
Best of luck.

Comment: I managed to update alright but find that my machine no longer recognises the correct resolution for the monitor connected via the docking station. I've posted about it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/593043/ubuntu-dell-e7240-docking-station-monitor-resolution-14-04
If you could offer any advice I would be grateful.